# Create new rows for each value, separated by comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
name,category,price
Apple, phone, 120,140,300
Samsung, phone, 200
Sony, TV, 600
Nokia, phone, 99,80
```

And I want to get the next pandas DataFrame

```
name,category,price
Apple, phone, 120
Apple, phone, 140
Apple, phone, 300
Samsung, phone, 200
Sony, TV, 600
Nokia, phone, 99
Nokia, phone, 80
```

What is the best way create such dataframe, especially if it consists of 1 million products? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the column **price** a list or a string?

Comment: @MatheusDouglas string

Comment: @politicalscientist why explode twice and worry about dropping anything? All he needs is `df.assign(price=df.price.str.split(',')).explode('price')`

Comment: @user3483203 not sure how I missed that you are totally right

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies, guys. Have a great day.